# Что значит :: знак в java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, лямбда-выражение

Часто вижу `::` при определении нового экземпляра, в стримах, иногда в лямда выражениях. Что он значит? Что значит `List :: stream`?

P.S. И как он называется?

Comment: В народе он называется "квадроточие".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Оператор "ссылка на метод"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (Method Reference). По сути - сокращенная запись для ссылки на метод из функционального интерфейса при использовании лямбды.

```
List::stream
```

является ссылкой на метод `stream()` из интерфейса `List`

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(1,2,3),
    Arrays.asList(4,5,6)
);
list.steam()
       .flatMap(List::stream)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

приведенный отрывок кода означает: 1. Мы инициализируем поток, в котором будет список чисел (`Stream<List<Integer>>`) 2. с помощью `flatMap` мы объединяем список чисел в поток чисел (`Stream<Integer>`) 3. с помощью `forEach` и ссылки на метод `println` для каждого элемента из потока вызывается вывод на экран

Если владеете английским, хорошее объяснение с примерами приведено [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245383/3905327)