# Объясните пожалуйста механизм работы ссылок на методы

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Всем привет. У меня в проекте есть необходимость переделывать список пользователей List в карту Map, где ключом будет Id пользователя.
Знаю, что способов много, но я решил использовать Stream API. 
Вот, как я решил это реализовать с использованием лямбды:

```
Map<Integer, User> result  = usersList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(user -> user.getUserId, user -> user));
```

а вот с использованием ссылки на метод:

```
Map<Integer, User> result  = usersList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getUserId, user -> user));
```

Первым аргументом функции toMap является некоторая реализация интерфейса `Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper`, внутри которого есть абстрактная функция `R apply(T t)`.

И теперь, если с 1м вариантом как бы всё понятно: мы явно говорим, что эта функция будет принимать юзера и возвращать его Id, то уже со 2м у меня возникает неразбериха.

Как мы можем передавать в качестве аргумента в функцию ссылку на не статический метод без явного использования объекта, т.е. почему с именем класса тоже прокатывает?

Я всегда думал, что с использованием ссылок на методы при вызове метода интерфейса будет использоваться переданный по ссылке метод класса или объекта. Тут мы видим, что метод `apply` принимает объект типа `T`, однако метод `getUserId` ничего не принимает. Где логика?
В теории два варианта должны дать следующее:

```
Function<User,Integer> keyMapper = new Function<User,Integer>() {
   @Override
   public Integer apply(User user) {
      return user.getUserId();
   }
};
```

Но как оно работает во 2м варианте я не понимаю
Надеюсь, что написал понятно. Объясните пожалуйста, что это за магия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему работает `::`: `String::length` эквивалентно `x -> x.length()`,`user -> user.getUserId` эквивалентно `User::getUserId`, т.е. это та же лямбда. [Подробнее о `::`.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869262/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-java)

> 1. `object::instanceMethod`
>
> Refer to an instance method using a reference to the supplied object,
>   as in `System.out::println`
>
> 2. `Class::staticMethod`
>
> Refer to static method, as in `Math::max`
>
> 3. `Class::instanceMethod`
>
> Invoke the instance method on a reference to an object supplied by the context, as in `String::length`

---

> Функциональный интерфейс `Function<T,R>` представляет функцию перехода
>   от объекта типа `T` к объекту типа `R`

Вроде как `apply` - метод, который "применяет" лямбду к параметру.
Но я могу ошибаться.

Пример:  `Function<Integer, Integer> squareFunction = x -> x*x;
 System.out.println(squareFunction.apply(5))`

Т.е., в `Collectors.toMap()` выполняет лямбду для каждого элемента листа, получает ключи для `map`.

Comment: Я всё равно не понимаю почему работает `::` У меня сейчас открыта книжка: Шилдт "Полное руководство" и вот, что там написано: Ссылки на методы экземпляра   `ссылка_на_объект::имя_метода`. откуда здесь имя класса вылазит

Comment: "метод, который "применяет" лямбду к параметру" всё верно, но у переданного метода getUserId не может быть параметров т.к он ничего не принимает

Comment: Ссылка на объект это и есть имя класса.

Comment: @ВладиславНовиков `apply` применяет `getUser` к `user`. То, что вы не видите, что передается параметр, не значит, что его нет. В данном случае параметр это каждый элемент list

Comment: нет, не путайте пожалуйста. это для ссылок на статические методы имя_класса::имя_метода (СТАТИЧЕСКИЙ)

Comment: Нет, это вы не путайте. `object::instanceMethod 
Refer to an instance method using a reference to the supplied object, as in System.out::println 
   Class::staticMethod 
 Refer to static method, as in Math::max 
   Class::instanceMethod 
Invoke the instance method on a reference to an object supplied by the context, as in String::length`

Comment: https://vk.com/doc232854130_379492516?hash=405558e82b966c17f9&dl=3ece8aa22d78980835 откройте пожалуйста 453 стр. Исходя из того, что написано в книге запись `SomeInterface obj = User::getUserId`  не должна работать т.к метод getUserId не статический. А вот так всё будет нормально `User obj = new User();   ...... obj::getUserId`

Comment: @ВладиславНовиков я не знаю, что написано в книге. Я отредактировал ответ, прочитайте его пожалуйста.

Comment: @AntonSorokin ссылка на объект это ссылка на объект. Если метод статический, это имя класса. Если метод не статический, это имя экземпляра класса. Владислав все правильно пишет.

Comment: @notaProgrammer а `Class::instanceMethod` - это что, имя экземпляра класса?

Comment: @AntonSorokin человек с репутацией 3500 не знает, что можно или как сделать ссылку на НЕ СТАТИЧЕСКИЙ метод?

Comment: @AntonSorokin `object::instanceMethod`. Тут `object` может быть как название класса, так и название экземпляра класса

Comment: @notaProgrammer что? я то понимаю. А вот влад пишет, что так делать нельзя, и так работать не должно

Comment: @notaProgrammer причем тут это? Автор вопроса пишет, что `Class::instanceMethod` работать не должно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89970/discussion-between-not-a-programmer-and-anton-sorokin).

Comment: @ВладиславНовиков ну что?

Comment: @AntonSorokin Я ещё раз внимательно пересмотрел Ваш ответ и, кажется, разобрался. Интуитивно я понимаю, что метод этого функционального интерфейса будет работать с элементом списка, а нам надо просто сказать какой метод вызвать. Почему-то в книге Шилдта говорится только про первые два случая, а про 3й ни слова. О нём я не знал, из-за чего и случился своеобразный сумбур. Видимо, надо почитать более "продвинутую" литературу на эту тему. Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Я немного поспешил вопросом, надо было тщательнее искать ответ.                         Всего может быть четыре вида ссылок на методы, подробнее о которых можно почитать в [официальной документации Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Вот три примера "быстрой" реализации интерфейса:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); 
MyInterface obj1 = myClass::methodFodInterfaceImpl
MyInterface obj2 = string -> string.hashCode();
MyInterface obj3 = String::hashCode;
```

Всем спасибо)